# .htaccess to remove the need for adding .html in the address bar versus creating new folders for all pages

Tags: .htaccess, optimization

I'm sure that with any effort I could figure out how to make this work inside of a .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

But, would that be more or less efficient than just creating a folder with new index.html in each folder?

For me, the real end result that I'm trying to achieve is to not require somebody to type:

skypodstudios.com/solar.html

I would rather let it be good enough to just type:

skypodstudios.com/solar

Both seem to accomplish it, I'm just wondering which is more efficient or if either are frowned upon?

Answer (score 0):

Using folders instead of files is a bad practice. You don't need a folder for each html file you create and it will only invite clutter. Using the .htaccess solution you specified is also not optimal since it will force you to put all your html files in one folder (and will not be useful if you use other file types).
I suggest you use one of the following instead:

For a **small project** with few files, include HTML files depending on the URI segment. You do that by telling your .htaccess to pass all url queries to your index file (usually index.php) and then that file breaks down the URL segments and retrieve the correct file from the correct folder.

For a **big project** with hundreds of files, ask yourself if you are using the same template (file structure) over and over again. If your project is a blog or a store chances are the answer is yes. If it is then instead of including files you'd better store your data in a database and then retrieve the current page's data via your index.php file using a database query.